# How to write a Flux task to calculate multiple percentiles in one go?

Tags: scripting, influxdb, flux

I am trying to write a Flux scheduled task in InfluxDB to sample monitoring data points over a period of time and obtain percentiles. Here is the code I have so far:

```
from(bucket: "dev-10s")
      |> range(start: -30m)
      |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "monitor")
      |> group(columns: ["metrics","instanceId"])
      |> quantile(q:0.8)
      |> map(fn: (r) => ({ r with _measurement: "80%" }))
      |> map(fn: (r) => ({ r with _field: "value" }))
      |> map(fn: (r) => ({ r with _time: r._stop }))
      |> to(bucket: "dev-30m", org: "rainge")
```

However, I need to calculate all percentiles from 10 to 100. If I have to call the quantile function separately for each percentile, the time complexity would be too high. I would like to calculate all percentiles in one go. Similar to the following C++ code:

```
bool big_or_equal(double a, double b) {
    return (a > b) || (abs(a - b) < 1e-8);
}

vector<double> calc_percentile(vector<double> data) {
    vector<double> percent({
                                   0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0
                           }
    );
    vector<double> result;
    int data_count = data.size();
    int cur_count = 0;
    sort(data.begin(), data.end());
    for (auto i: data) {
        ++cur_count;
        double cur_percent = cur_count * 1.0 / data_count;
        if (big_or_equal(cur_percent, percent[result.size()])) {
            result.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am a beginner in Flux programming and have limited knowledge of functional programming. I tried to approach the problem using a C++ approach but found that Flux does not have a for loop. When I attempted to use the map function as a substitute for a for loop (I'm not sure if this is the correct approach), I encountered an issue where the anonymous function inside map was unable to modify an external counter. I have tried reading the documentation on InfluxDB and even used chatgpt to solve the problem, but to no avail.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!